# How to specialize `swap` for classes with bitfield members?

Tags: c++, swap, bit-fields

Let's say I have a C++ struct:

```
struct Clazz {
    uint8_t a : 2;
    uint8_t b : 6;
};
```

I want to be able to swap elements of this class as quickly as possible. Is it better to just call `std::swap(cl1, cl2)` or to specialize, and how? Will this work?

```
Clazz:swap(Clazz& other) {
    std::swap(a, other.a);
    std::swap(b, other.b); // how to make C++ swap the whole uint8_t value at once?
}
```

Comment: You should try not defining your own swap, and look at the assembly generated for `std::swap`. There's a good chance the optimizer is smart enough to copy the `uint8_t` around as a whole. If your real class contains other stuff too for which you need to implement `swap` yourself, then once again, look at the assembly to make sure the optimizer hasn't combined the swaps you have in the implementation above. If that doesn't work, then an (anonymous) union with a `struct` containing the members above and another `uint8_t` member might be worth looking into. In all cases, examine assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you had the following code:

```
struct Clazz {
    uint8_t a : 2;
    uint8_t b : 6;
};

Clazz c1,c2;
c1.a = 1; c1.b = 61;
c2.a = 3; c2.b = 63;
```

You could just do a `std::swap(c1, c2)` with no additional swap functions in your class and things will swap as expected. Mind you, the results may vary based on implementation, and a cursory performance test ([based on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34700947/1152524)) shows that a custom swap (in the case of this code) may be more optimal. Thanks to user Nax's [reminder of timing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700847/how-to-specialize-swap-for-classes-with-bitfield-members/34701333?noredirect=1#comment57152418_34701333), I've edited my test code below to take larger sets into account.

When the below test code was compile in `g++ 4.2.1` without optimizations, the rough average for the `std::swap` loop came to be `0.00523261 us` while the `Clazz:swap` rough average came to `0.00996584 us`. This would imply that the `std::swap` implementation was faster than `reinterpret_cast`'ing the `Clazz` object to a `uint8_t`, however, when you turn on maximum optimizations (`-O3`), the times were much more noticeable, with the `std::swap` loop coming in at `0.00102523 us` and the `Clazz::swap` loop coming to `0.000739868 us`, a significant increase in speed over the `std::swap` method.

Additionally, if your `Clazz` object were to become more complex to need more than the default constructor, such that you had to include a copy constructor, the times for the `std::swap` will almost double as most implementations will use the copy constructor of an object when a temporary is created. Adding an empty default constructor and a copy constructor (i.e. `Clazz(const Clazz& cp) : a(cp.a), b(cp.b) {}`) to the `Clazz` object changed the `std::swap` times to the following: `no optimizations ~ 0.0104058 us`, `-O3 ~ 0.00241034 us`; a doubling of times, while the `Clazz::swap` method stayed consistent.

To this, if you wish to have the `std::swap` method call your custom `Clazz::swap` method, there are a couple of ways to achieve this since the `std::swap` method doesn't automatically make a call to any classes defined `swap` method (that is `std::swap` doesn't call `a.swap(b)`).

You could overload the `std::swap` method with your specialized class directly, example:

```
namespace std {
    void swap(Clazz& a, Clazz& b)
    {
        std::swap(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(a), reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(b));
        /* or a.swap(b) if your Clazz has private types that need to be
        accounted for and you provide a public swap method */
    }
}
```

Doing this, however, means this specialization will not be found by [argument-dependant lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), so calling `swap(a, b)` isn't the same as `std::swap(a, b)`.

To satisfy the ADL, you could just include the `swap` method inside the same namespace of your `Clazz` object (be it the global namespace or a named/anonymous namespace), example:

```
using std::swap;

namespace ClazzNS {
    struct Clazz {
        uint8_t a : 2;
        uint8_t b : 6;
    };
    
    void swap(Clazz& a, Clazz& b)
    {
        std::swap(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(a), reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(b));
        /* or a.swap(b) if your Clazz has private types that need to be
        accounted for and you provide a public swap method */
    }
}

int main()
{
    ClazzNS::Clazz c1,c2;
    c1.a = 1; c1.b = 61;
    c2.a = 3; c2.b = 63;
    swap(c1, c2); // calls ClazzNS::swap over std::swap
}
```

This is just so you can call `swap(a, b)` without having to be explicit about namespace.

If you were pedantic, you could mix it together to get the following:

```
namespace ClazzNS {
    struct Clazz {
        uint8_t a : 2;
        uint8_t b : 6;

        void swap(ClazzNS::Clazz& other)
        {
            std::swap(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(*this), reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(other));
        }
    };
    
    void swap(ClazzNS::Clazz& a, ClazzNS::Clazz& b)
    {
        a.swap(b);
    }
}

namespace std {
    void swap(ClazzNS::Clazz& a, ClazzNS::Clazz& b)
    {
        ClazzNS::swap(a, b);
        /*
        you could also directly just call
        std::swap(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(a), reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(b))
        or a.swap(b) if you wanted to avoid
        multiple function calls */
    }
}

int main()
{
    ClazzNS::Clazz c1,c2;
    c1.a = 1; c1.b = 61;
    c2.a = 3; c2.b = 63;
    c1.swap(c2); // calls ClazzNS::Clazz::swap 
    swap(c1, c2); // calls ClazzNS::swap
    std::swap(c1, c2); // calls the overloaded std::swap
}
```

You're results may vary and it's ultimately up to you how you implement your swap method, but it's always best to test it out yourself; I hope these numbers can help.

#### C++ test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <csignal>

struct Clazz {
    uint8_t a : 2;
    uint8_t b : 6;
    
    void swap(Clazz& other)
    {
        std::swap(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(*this), reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(other));
    }
};

static double elapsed_us(struct timespec init, struct timespec end)
{
    return ((end.tv_sec - init.tv_sec) * 1000000) + (static_cast<double>((end.tv_nsec - init.tv_nsec)) / 1000);
}

static void printall(const Clazz& c1, const Clazz& c2)
{
    std::cout << "c1.a:" << static_cast<unsigned int>(c1.a) << ", c1.b:" << static_cast<unsigned int>(c1.b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c2.a:" << static_cast<unsigned int>(c2.a) << ", c2.b:" << static_cast<unsigned int>(c2.b) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int max_cnt = 100000001;
    struct timespec init, end;
    Clazz c1, c2;
    c1.a = 1; c1.b = 61;
    c2.a = 3; c2.b = 63;
    printall(c1, c2);
    
    std::cout << "std::swap" << std::endl;
    std::swap(c1, c2); // to show they actually swap
    printall(c1, c2);
    
    std::cout << "c1.swap(c2)" << std::endl;
    c1.swap(c2); // to show again they actually swap
    printall(c1, c2);
    
    std::cout << "std::swap loop" << std::endl;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &init);
    for (int i = 0; i < max_cnt; ++i) {
        std::swap(c1, c2);
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    printall(c1, c2);
    // rough estimate of timing / divide by iterations
    std::cout << "std::swap avg. us = " << (elapsed_us(init, end) / max_cnt) << " us" << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "Clazz::swap loop" << std::endl;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &init);
    for (int i = 0; i < max_cnt; ++i) {
        c1.swap(c2);
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    printall(c1, c2);
    // rough estimate of timing / divide by iterations
    std::cout << "Clazz:swap avg. us = " << (elapsed_us(init, end) / max_cnt) << " us" << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: This is not a proper way to benchmark, you should try to swap a huge number of values (let's say, 100000), measure that, and then divide so you get the average time per swap. 4us seems a bit long for such a simple operation, most of the 4us seems to come from the `tick` overhead rather than the swap function.

Comment: @Nax, well `max_cnt` is equal to `100001`, so I'm swapping 1 more than your max to get an average of the swap operation (since the OP asked about `std::swap` vs. a custom swap). Additionally, I've edited my post to remove the `tick` function (inlined the `clock_gettime` function) and received the same results. It should be noted this is supposed to be a simple test for simple/quick results, so given they came from a VM on an i7 single thread @ 2.2 GHz, I'd actually say 4/1000000 of 1 second actually seems average given what's being swapped and how :)

Comment: After moving the timing out of the loop, I can get much better results. When unoptimized, with 10,000,000 runs, I get 14ns/swap with `std::swap` and 7ns with the custom one, a clear sign that memberwise swap takes place (hence the x2 time). With optimization, I get funky, <0.1 ns times, a clear sign that my compiler is much smarter than me and completely broke the benchmark.

Comment: Just to be clear, the problem with your benchmark is that you start and stop the clock inside the loop, so you also benchmark the 2nd call to `clock_gettime` at each iteration. This involve a context switch, hence the 4us.

Comment: @Nax, that's what I get for not sleeping and having my coffee before checking my work :) I copied some "worst case" scenario timing code from a testing framework I sometimes use to do performance testing and forgot to carry the 1 basically; you also reminded me of the copy constructor use in `std::swap`, so thanks for that reminder and info! I've edited my answer to include you're notes and some other edits.

Comment: No problem :) our results still differ, but that's probably because you used `g++` while I used `clang++`. At least now it's in the nanosecond range, much more acceptable on modern CPUs :)

Comment: I I define `a.swap(b)`, do I need to define the free-function version too? I thought `std::swap` would use the member function automagically.

Comment: @quant_dev, I modified my answer to make note of this, but `std::swap` doesn't call a member defined swap function; the free-function version is for use of `ADL` .. that is, if someone using your code wanted to swap 2 `Clazz` objects and assumed `using namespace std` or `using std::swap` was used and just did `swap(a, b);`, your optimized swap free-function would be called over the actual library `std::swap` function, and if you wanted to ensure your optimized version was called even when `std::swap` was used, you could override it as mentioned in the answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I expect adequte compiler to do it correctly without swap provided by you, so you should measure what will be faster but one thing you may want to try is to cast to uint8_t

```
void Clazz::swap(Clazz& other) {
    std::swap(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(*this), reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(other))
}
```

or just rewrite swap using memcpy

Ok, now just go and compile code. Tested with gcc5.2 with -O2 optimization level:

```
void test1(Clazz& a, Clazz& b) {
  a.swap(b);
}

void test2(Clazz& a, Clazz& b) {
  std::swap(a, b);
}
```

Generated code:

```
test1(Clazz&, Clazz&):
    movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
    movzbl  (%rsi), %edx
    movb    %dl, (%rdi)
    movb    %al, (%rsi)
    ret
test2(Clazz&, Clazz&):
    movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
    movzbl  (%rsi), %edx
    movb    %dl, (%rdi)
    movb    %al, (%rsi)
    ret
```

[DEMO](http://goo.gl/beNrHx)

Comment: You could avoid the reinterpret_cast with a union of the bitfield and a uint8_t.

Comment: @LeftoverPi: It's undefined behavior to read a different union member than the one most recently written to.